# How to determine if an fd can be read with os.read(fd,[buffer[) without hanging?

Tags: python

Before doing: `os.read(fd,1024)` I would like to check that there will be output rather than it hanging until output it received. Since fd is an int object, I can't do:

```
os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size
```

If I could get the size, I could check it is not 0.

Sorry if this is really simple, I am new to python.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`select.select`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select). (In windows, you can only it with socket):

```
import select

...

r, _, _ = select.select([fd], [], [], 0)
if r:
    data = os.read(fd, 1024)
```

Comment: should this work in pty environment? I am reading stdout of the python program (which is running: pty.spawn(/bin/sh)) from another process (not python) with proc_open. Still getting the hanging problem with the above code. If there is output it will read it, if there isn't, it will hang and way.

Comment: @OBV, `select.select` will return immediately with `timeout` (the fourth argument) as 0.

Comment: is that meant as select.select([fd]... rather?

Comment: @OBV: I distinctly remember answering a question about `pty.spawn()` and `proc_open()` very recently but I can't find it now. Was it your question? Here's the gist of the answer: `pty.spawn` accepts callbacks and when they are called, `os.read` won't block. See [code example in the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html#pty.spawn). I also mentioned that it looked like [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) meaning that you should update your question and provide more details about the context of your question.

Comment: Hi, yes I accidentally deleted it when trying to delete another one, thank you for that.  I tried your suggestion, and I can get the buffer size, but again, same hanging issue. Falsetru's answer is also same problem, quite frustrating.. In it, r is always true, but if I try to read even 1 character and there isn't output, it hangs and waits.

Comment: @falsetru J.F. Sebastian XY problem clarified, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457648/python-os-read-blocking-on-fd-nothing-i-have-tried-works-so-far-see-example