# Python: os.read() blocking on fd

Tags: python, linux

How to avoid the problem of line buffering if the fd is a bash shell?

Comment: check select module http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html

Comment: @PasteBT done- no change, added to list.

Comment: @PasteBT: if `read` callback is called; it means that `os.read()` won't block i.e., you don't need `select` if you use the callback

Comment: `/bin/sh` won't quit until you say it to quit (`exit` or EOF on its stdin).

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian I don't want it to quit, please see the context at the top of the post Sebastian. I just want to be able to continue to read output and not get blocked if there is nothing there (so return something to tell the control process that data is none- instead of get stuck waiting for output).

Comment: @OBV: how do you know in a terminal that there is no more output while `sh` keeps running? By searching for its prompt? It might be enough for a limited set of grandchild subprocesses but in general it will break. Or by sending it `echo SOME_UNIQ_IDENTIFIER` and looking for it in the output? It also looks hackish. Or by combining the two approaches i.e., set `sh` prompt to a unique identifier and look for each in the output.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian I thought of sending input everytime before reading output (unique identifier) but what if program.py is running a program such as "su" that asks for a password, it will then receive the unique identifier ahead of the password the user enters. As for first point- I just assumed that is the case because if I try to read even a single extra character more it will be stuck. Maybe we could try reading in a thread with a timeout?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian Just tried your suggestion,-but the same problem exists, on each read of output the unique identifier is present to mark the end of the output, but it seems like the output buffer is filled one part at time. Like first buffer is 6 bytes: whoami then 6: nobody. so two reads of stdout with unique identifier added gives: 9 bytes: whoamixyz then read again: 9 bytes: nobodyxyz.. so it still doesn't tell me if its safe to read again as I cant tell if there is anything else being queued up by the SH after I read its stdout.

Comment: @OBV: You misunderstood. The thing that sends `whoami` can send `whoami; echo something_unique` *or* set `PS1` to something unique and read until it is found.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian I see, but as I say, SH only queues part of the output at a time and wont serve the next part until you read the previous. So in a simple "whoami" command, there is 3 buffer reads required. If you read the whole buffer the first time, you will only get "whoami" back, if you read it again, you get "nobody", if you read it again, you get "sh-1$:" It is at this point that if I read it again, it will blocking, but before that, I can't tell if that is the last required read to get the whole output. Understand what I mean? I assume it does it this way so that the xterminal can format

Comment: @OBV: you can tell by looking at `'sh-1$:'`. If you found it; stop reading.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian sorry finally got your point, my bad. I would worry about it being 'hacking' as you say, in case of "su" you would have to predict the unique identifier every time, and probably other scenarios too that might break it eventually. What is your opinion on using a thread for os.read as a potential solution?

Comment: @OBV: if `su` changes `$PS1` then it will break the method based on it. It won't break `command; echo something_unique` method (`echo` is executed *after* the command completes that is the point). Thread and everything else won't help you: **python (the `read` callback) already reads the output in a nonblocking manner**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a summary of what I've understood from your question and comments plus an unsatisfactory workaround at the end of the answer. The summary should help others to answer your question.

It seems you have a program (non-python) that wants to execute arbitrary shell commands that might require a tty ([Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)) and you have chosen as a solution to execute a Python script that runs `pty.spawn("/bin/sh", read_callback)` and write/read to its stdin/stdout.

And now you have a problem that you can't find the end of output for a shell command i.e., you don't know when to stop reading `program.py` stdout and if you try to read too much then your non-python program blocks.

First of all, `os.read` inside `read_callback` **does not block**. It may return less than 1024 bytes but it doesn't block:

```
def read_callback(fd):
    data = os.read(fd, 1024) # <-- this doesn't block
    return data
```

Though it doesn't help when the parent program tries to read.

#### Workaround

To avoid blocking on read, the parent can change `PS1` environment in the running `sh` to some unique value or inject `echo something_unique` after each command. Then it can read one byte at a time until it reads `something_unique`. It should stop at this point.

As an alternative you could try to make the pipes nonblocking *in your parent* and read more than one byte at a time. Or use an exchange protocol that defines clear message boundaries and run shell commands one by one e.g., using `pexpect.run()` (to detect the end of output easily in the Python side).

Comment: Thank you, I think I may try it see how it goes, and then solve the 'hacking' problems as and when they come up. Thanks for your input,  really appreciate it.

Comment: @OBV: the word is [hack-*ish* as in "poorly designed workarounds"](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hackish).

Comment: I justed tested the command; echo "identifier" theory. It doesn't work for all interactive programs... because for example, if I ran "netcat: nc -lnvp 5000" output: listening on any [5000]... It won't echo "test" until after the program ends. :/ Any other ideas? (In addition, "su; echo 'test';" doesn't work, "test" isn't echo'd after you switch user..

Comment: @OBV: both work as expected: wait for the program to complete (as a proxy for "no more output will be produced" (we can't use EOF as an indicator because `sh` is still running)) and only then echo unique id. Even for `su` case; you'll see the `echo` output if you exit the session. The `nc` example shows that you want your script to know arbitrary network protocols as well to understand when a message (if it is even a message-based protocol) is complete. Solution is to push data instead of polling it. How to do it depends on what the parent program is.

Comment: but how can you react to stdin on interactive programs if you don't get the End of Out signal until after the program ends?? The control process is the middle-man between the user and shell. So running programs and interacting with them by the user is necessary.

Comment: @OBV: If there is a human involved and you need to run arbitrary commands then *drop the parent program*. `master_read` and `stdin_read` callbacks allows you to modify both input and output if it is what you want.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by drop the parent program? The parent program is the middleman- yes human involved, but they can only see what the controlling program can see (stdout from python program). How can this help the issue of the buffer problem?

Comment: @OBV: If you want universal support (arbitrary commands with arbitrary input/output); you need to drop the program that can't work with tty directly. there is no buffer problem on `pty.spawn` side.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

import os
import pty
#mport sys
import fcntl

OFLAGS = None

def set_nonblocking(file_handle):
    """Make a file_handle non-blocking."""
    global OFLAGS
    OFLAGS = fcntl.fcntl(file_handle, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    nflags = OFLAGS | os.O_NONBLOCK
    fcntl.fcntl(file_handle, fcntl.F_SETFL, nflags)


def main():
    (pid, file_handle) = pty.fork()
    if pid == 0:
        # we're in the child
        os.execl('/bin/sh', '/bin/sh', '-i')
    else:
        #file_handle = os.open('/dev/null', os.O_RDONLY)
        set_nonblocking(file_handle)
        while True:
            try:
                # return 1-n bytes or exception if no bytes
                data = os.read(file_handle, 1024)
            except BlockingIOError:
                #sys.stdout.write('no data read\r')
                pass
            else:
                print(len(data), data)

main()
```

Sometimes the way to deal with nonblocking I/O, is to use a thread or subprocess, BTW.  Then one thread or subprocess can block while others merrily do their work.

HTH

Comment: OP runs `program.py` in a script in some other language (PHP). Imagine your code is in `program.py`: how does it help to find the end of output from a shell command sent to `sh`?

Comment: For that, it's reasonable to check if the pid has exited.

Comment: @dstromberg can you illustrate that please?

Comment: It should be a matter of using os.waitpid with a WNOHANG option, inside a loop.